# Previous even number

Tags: c++, optimization, micro-optimization

If an integer is uneven (odd), I would like to get the previous number, otherwise I would like to keep the current number. E.g. if `x = 3`, I would like to assign `2` to `x`, if `x = 4`, then nothing happens.

At the moment, I do the following: `x = (x/2)*2`, but I have heard that division is computational expensive. Does `-O3` optimize this expression? I am using the `c++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4` compiler. `x` is a `uint32_t`.

Comment: `x = x - (x & 1)` perhaps?

Comment: `x = (x >> 1) << 1;` You can use shifts, but the compiler likely optimizes the multiplication and division to this anyway.

Comment: You could also use `x &= ~1`, which should compile into a single `AND` by a constant.

Comment: You could go with `(x & 0xFFFFFFFE)` but I am forced to wonder is this _really_ the bottleneck of your program and is this sort of femto-optimization the best use of your time?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
x &= ~1;
```

I suppose that x is declared as having type `int`. Otherwise if the rank of type x is greater than the rank of type int then you should use an integer literal of the type of the variable x.